# Custom object in prepareForSegue is different from viewDidLoad

Tags: viewdidload

Here is what i am trying to achieve:
I programmatically add a set of custom objects. Each of these on tap should perform an existing segue. In `performForSegue`, I set some property of the destinationViewController.

Here is the setup:
I have a custom object CustomButton which has a property CustomProperty. In my main view I have a `NSMutableArray` which is populated with instances of these objects. A tap recognizer is hooked up to the custom button. Also there is a segue between the main view and another view which is performed when the custom button is clicked. I also have a prepareForSegue where I do some processing.

Main viewDidLoad looks like:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{  
    buttons = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    CustomButton *customButton1 = [[CustomButton alloc] init];                

    // Attach touch recognizers
    UITapGestureRecognizer *singleFingerTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(customButtonPressed:)];
    [customButton1 addGestureRecognizer:singleFingerTap];
    [self.view addSubview:customButton1];

    // Add it to the buttons array
    [self.buttons addObject:customButton1];

    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSLog(@"---------viewDidLoad-----------");
    NSLog(@"count = %u", buttons.count);
    for (id tempButton in buttons)
    {
        NSLog(@"Custom Property = %@", ((CustomButton *)tempButton).customProperty);
    }
}
```

prepareForSegue looks like

```
- (void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender 
{
    NSLog(@"---------prepareForSegue-----------");
    NSLog(@"count = %u", buttons.count);
    for (id tempButton in buttons)
    {
        NSLog(@"Content = %@", ((CustomButton *)tempButton).customProperty);
    }
}
```

When I run this application and viewDidLoad is called the count and customProperty is printed as expected. On pressing the button prepareForSegue is called and the count is 1 (as expected) but the customProperty is null.

Any idea what is going one?

Answer (score 0):

In your `viewDidLoad` you're working with an object of class `CustomButton`. But in `prepareForSegue` you cast the object to a `BookButton`. I assume, that this is not intended and the reason `customProperty` is nil, because it's a) not set and b) there's no such property in `BookButton`.

Comment: Sorry, I was trying to remove my business logic names to be clearer but guess made it more confusing. Fixed the question now.

Comment: Please make sure, that you always work with the correct object. You are referencing `buttons` sometimes prefixed with `self` and sometime without.